# DMPfold: number of models produced using "10 500" feature in "run_dmpfold.sh"?

Tags: protein-structure

I ran this command:

```
run_dmpfold.sh sequence.fasta sequence.21c sequence.map ./folder 10 500
```

From my previous discussion, I understand that I should run with default "run_dmpfold.sh" parameters i.e. `3 50`; however, since I have already run the `10 500` I have some questions.

I see that after generating "sequence_1.pdb to sequence_500.pdb" files, these files are no more in the folder and, now I see "ensemble_1.pdb". 
Will there be more ensemble files like "ensemble_500.pdb" and "sequence_n.pdb" files? I mean when can I expect "final_1.pdb' file? Also, I see files like "CLUSTERS_001.pdb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sequence_n.pdb` files are temporary and are combined into an `ensemble.i.pdb` file after each iteration `i`. That file has many structures in. After the run is complete there will be a `final_1.pdb` file. Don't worry about the cluster files. If you are interested in what they do, consult the `run_dmpfold.sh` script and see what it is doing line by line.

As I have said multiple times elsewhere, you should run the script with default parameters and let it run *to completion*. Then use the `final_1.pdb` and any other `final_*.pdb` files as the output. If you want more structures, use the `ensemble.i.pdb` files.